# Query outputting more records than it should do

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have an SQL query wtih a lot of joins. The fact is that before the query had to join the StudentClass table and Class table, it outputted the correct amount of rows which should be 4 rows. But when I include the Class and StudentClass tables, then it outputs 6 rows when it should still output 4 rows. The problem is that if a student is taking 2 modules and are in 2 classes, then it outputs 4 modules which is the 2 modules duplicated and 4 classes with the 2 classes duplicated. Why is this happening, is it something wrong with the way I set up the tables or is it the query?

Below is the PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>Exam Grade Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $query = "
          SELECT * FROM Course c
            INNER JOIN CourseModule cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
            JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId 
            JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId
            JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
            JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId
            JOIN StudentClass sc ON st.StudentId = sc.StudentId
            JOIN Class cl ON sc.ClassId = cl.ClassId 
          WHERE
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."' = '' OR cl.CourseId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."' = '' OR cl.ModuleId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($classid)."' = '' OR sc.ClassId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($classid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid)."' = '' OR s.TeacherId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."' = '' OR gr.StudentId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."' = '' OR gr.Grade = '".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."')
          ORDER BY $orderfield ASC";

        $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));
        mysql_close();

    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want to show the query result and tables which I have got on a word document. How can I attach a word file by the way so that you can all open up the word document if you want to?

Thank You

Comment: this is a code overload. Try minimizing the amount of code, and only show the snippet which is relevant

Comment: If you're asking an SQL query question, then don't include 5 miles worth of PHP and HTML... Show the actual SQL that's causing the problem, and may be some details about the table structures.

Comment: What are you trying to group on? Student? StudentClass? What information are you trying to extract (you might want to replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT [field], [field], [field]` as this will 1) reduce the amount of data being returned and 2) give us an idea of the information you're attempting to extract).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing all the JOINs to LEFT JOINs?